# Difference between "implicit declaration of function" and the original version of the function

Tags: c, linux, sleep

I use gcc4.8. And I wrote such code, using sleep.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* I know it's worong to pass a floating number to sleep
     * this is only for testing. */
    sleep(0.001);               
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with "gcc -Wall a.c -o a", got warning "implicit declaration of function ‘sleep’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]". Then I ran it, this program sleeps approximately 1 second (it seems sleep ceils 0.001 to 1).

Then I change the code to be like this:

```
#include <unistd.h> /* add header file */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* I know it's worong to pass a floating number to sleep
     * this is only for testing. */
    sleep(0.001);               
    return 0;
}
```

This time it only sleeps 0 second, seems like sleep floors 0.001 to 0.

Shouldn't these two sleep be identical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first (wrong) case a real floating point value is given to sleep as it is assumed that the prototype of `sleep` takes a floating point value (a `double` actually). `sleep` will interpret the bit representation of this `double` as an `int` and wait for so many seconds. You are lucky that this is only 1 second. In the second case the floating point value is cast to an `int` with rounding to 0.

Comment: So the first situation is like adding `unsigned int sleep(double t);` at the beginning?

Comment: More likely `int sleep(double t)` as traditionally an implicit declaration always returns `int`. That goes back to the early versions of C.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, please always use the `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` compilation option to prevent the damage from the compiler/linker's *smart* default behavior.

By compiling the two cases into two executables `sleep_include_no`(1st wrong case, without include) and `sleep_include_yes`(2nd ok case, with include), I did some simple tests:

```
## 'sleep' will invoke the 'nanosleep', and use strace to show real duration
$ strace ./sleep_include_no 2>&1 | grep nanosleep
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7ffee0165970) = 0

$ strace ./sleep_include_yes 2>&1 | grep nanosleep
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7ffce92eedd0) = 0
```

The asm code snip from output of gdb's `disas` command:

```
/* 1st wrong case (without include), compiler/linker's default behavior, \
   an immediate constant '0x1' is set into %eax as parameter of sleep */
=> 0x0000555555555141 <+8>:     movsd  0xebf(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x555555556008
   0x0000555555555149 <+16>:    movsd  %xmm0,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x000055555555514e <+21>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000555555555152 <+25>:    movq   %rax,%xmm0
   0x0000555555555157 <+30>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x000055555555515c <+35>:    call   0x555555555030 <sleep@plt>

/* 2nd ok case (with include), \
   the 'cvttsd2si' instruction is something like cast double to int */
=> 0x0000555555555141 <+8>:     movsd  0xebf(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x555555556008
   0x0000555555555149 <+16>:    movsd  %xmm0,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x000055555555514e <+21>:    movsd  -0x8(%rbp),%xmm0
   0x0000555555555153 <+26>:    cvttsd2si %xmm0,%rax
   0x0000555555555158 <+31>:    mov    %eax,%edi
   0x000055555555515a <+33>:    call   0x555555555030 <sleep@plt>
```

So the compiler/linker just make it works, but probably not what you expected. I think this is because the compiler has so many legacy features to deal with and compatibility considerations to accommodate, we should not blame on it. As a programmer the only thing I can do is using `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` to raise a forced alarm.

P.S. Share a bloody production bug raised by not including the user defined API header file and ignoring the **implicit declaration of function** warning. Here is the demo code (3 source files):

```
$ cat my_lib.h
#ifndef _my_lib_h_
#define _my_lib_h_
long long get_i64_from_my_lib(); 
#endif

$ cat my_lib.c
#include "my_lib.h"
long long get_i64_from_my_lib() {
        return 113840990519587; /* 6789 ABCD 0123 */
}

$ cat main.c 
#include <stdio.h>
/* #include "my_lib.h" (without this include, the result is buggy) */
int main() {
        long long i64 = get_i64_from_my_lib();
        printf("%lld, %0lx\n", i64, i64);
}

$ gcc -g -c my_lib.c
$ ar -cq my_lib.a my_lib.o
$ gcc -g -o my_exe main.c my_lib.a  ## emit implicit-function-declaration warning

## The returned type is not an expected i64, but a truncated i32. \
## When the returned value is less than 2^31, the function seems ok, \
## so it is an evil bug.
$ ./my_exe 
-1412628189, ffffffffabcd0123
```