# Why does sleep() work even if I don't include <unistd.h>?

Tags: c, sleep, unistd.h

I can use `sleep` in `c` without including `<unistd.h>`, but `gcc` will report:

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'sleep' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

But it still works. For example, I can call `sleep(8)` and I use the `time()` function to count time, and I can see 8 seconds elapsed.

Why is it reporting this warning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "implicit declaration of function" and the original version of the function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361006/difference-between-implicit-declaration-of-function-and-the-original-version-o)

Comment: @JosephYoung Not really a duplicate of that question, which is asking why it behaves *different*, not why it works *in the first place*.